# When use CTC-loss for speech recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, speech-recognition

I'm trying to understand and implement CTC-loss for speech recognition ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57292896/understanding-ctc-loss-for-speech-recognition-in-keras) on SO). I'll like to have more information about the use cases of this technique.

From what i understood, it is more dedicated to understand **sentences** (e.g. "Please close the door.") than **word commands** (e.g. "close") as it's efficient to learn the sentence's structure (spaces, end of sentence) and fitted to recognize unknown words from the training set.

But considering a "some commands versus the rest" problem, could ctc-loss technique be more efficient than a classical deep learning classifier?

**Example**:

- **Classical model** has 5 classes, 4 are commands ("open", "close", "enter", "exit) and the fifth is a garbage which takes whatever that is not a command.
- **CTC-loss model** "translate" letter by letter every words and then we check if it's a command.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For short commands you can use more simple model, not necessary end-to-end CTC loss. There is extensive research about that. You need to google for "Keyword spotting". For references you can check

https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.03814

For something simple check

https://github.com/ARM-software/ML-KWS-for-MCU